# Azure publish completes, but the site shows next steps to deploy

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have an asp.net core 2.0 website built in VS19 that I am deploying to an Azure app service. The source code repo is in Azure Dev Ops, but I want to deploy directly from my local machine.

In Azure I created the Azure App Service and downloaded the 'Publish Profile' and imported it to VS2019 and executed the Publish. The output window shows that everything was deployed successfully.

[image]

However, when I navigate to the deployment url, I get this screen instead of my app.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? There isn't any error messages, so I can't really search.

EDIT: In startup.cs, my default route is in an Area. So I have the following defined:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areaRoute",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}");


        routes.MapAreaRoute(
            name: "default",
            areaName: "Home",
            template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "default",
        //    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you dont have the starting page above the hostingstart.html . Make sure you default page is listed in here and is above hostingstart.html so that will be picked by default.

If you are wondering how to do

**On Windows OS:**

**“App Services” blade > Select your “Web app”, click on “Configuration”  and Default Documents "**

**Linux OS:**

If the webApp has linux OS it wont have the default documents, you need to set 
the startup command as **`dotnet yourapp.dll`**  under general settings

[image]

Also make sure to check "Remove additional files at destination button during republish" on Visual Studio. That will remove the files existing in the WebApp before upload the files.

Comment: In configuration, I don't see a 'Default Documents' option. Also, in my startup.cs file I have set the route as follows:

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areaRoute",
                    template: "{area=Home}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}");
}

Comment: check the attached screenshot

Comment: I don't have that 'Default Documents' tab. Is there a way that I can set this in code? https://imgur.com/a/ha5iSQi

Comment: did you create a web app?

Comment: yes correct. Created a web app. Not sure if this changes anything, but in the 'Runtime stack' I chose .NET Core 2.0, and the OS defaulted to Linux. I also added my route config to the original question above.

Comment: I get it the above one is valid only for windows . if its linux set the startup command as  dotnet yourapp.dll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197903/discussion-between-reza-and-sajeetharan-msft).